# How to convert quarterly/monthly data to POSIXct or Date

Tags: r, date, posixct

I am trying to Import data from the ECB's Statistical Data Warehouse and have written the following function:

```
read.sdw<-function(key, startdate, enddate){
  df<-read.csv(paste("http://sdw.ecb.europa.eu/quickviewexport.do?start=", startdate, "&end=", enddate, "&SERIES_KEY=", key=key, "&type=csv", sep=""), skip=4)
  df
}
```

with, for example:

```
start.date<-"01-01-2010"
end.date<-"31-12-2012"
key<-"RDF.Q.AT.EUR.4F.CR.DCGDPG.RO"
```

The problem now is that I have monthly or quarterly data of the form:

```
     Period.Unit. X.Percentage.change..
1      2000Dec                   9.6
2      2000Nov                   9.3
3      2000Oct                   9.8
4      2000Sep                  10.1
5      2000Aug                   9.6
6      2000Jul                   9.1
```

or

```
  Period.Unit. X.Percent..
1       2012Q4       -4.23
2       2012Q3       -3.21
3       2012Q2       -4.39
4       2012Q1       -4.30
5       2011Q4       -4.40
6       2011Q3       -3.58

> dput(head(df))
structure(list(Period.Unit. = structure(c(12L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 
8L, 7L), .Label = c("2010Q1", "2010Q2", "2010Q3", "2010Q4", "2011Q1", 
"2011Q2", "2011Q3", "2011Q4", "2012Q1", "2012Q2", "2012Q3", "2012Q4"
), class = "factor"), X.Percent.. = c(-4.23, -3.21, -4.39, -4.3, 
-4.4, -3.58)), .Names = c("Period.Unit.", "X.Percent.."), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

How can I convert the time-column to `POSIXct` or `Date` to be able to work with it?

I already tried

```
df[,1]<-paste(df[,1], 1, sep="")
df[,1]<-as.Date(df[,1], "%Y%b%d")
```

for the monthly data, but this leads to `NA`s in the time-column.

Comment: for the quarter matter you probably need to have a look at `as.yearqtr` from the `zoo` package. For the month matter, your way works for me

Comment: Thanks. For the monthly data I get `NA`s in every field in which the English format in the data deviates from the German one (e.g. 2010Dec instead of 2010Dez). Is it possible that this is part of the problem?

Comment: it is more than likely that this is the problem. Maybe you can set your local settings to German to circumvent that ?

Comment: I changed the settings in RStudio to German, still not working though.

Comment: then you may need to create a table with the correspondances to modify the things that do not match between the 2 languages

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the quarter problem, you can do:

```
library(zoo)
df$date <- as.Date(as.yearqtr(df[, 1], format="%YQ%q"))

df
#  Period.Unit. X.Percent..       date
#1       2012Q4       -4.23 2012-10-01
#2       2012Q3       -3.21 2012-07-01
#3       2012Q2       -4.39 2012-04-01
#4       2012Q1       -4.30 2012-01-01
#5       2011Q4       -4.40 2011-10-01
#6       2011Q3       -3.58 2011-07-01
```

*NB: If you want to get the last day of the period, instead of the first, you can use argument "frac":*

```
df$date2 <- as.Date(as.yearqtr(df[, 1], format="%YQ%q"), frac=1)

df
#   Period.Unit. X.Percent..       date      date2
# 1       2012Q4       -4.23 2012-10-01 2012-12-31
# 2       2012Q3       -3.21 2012-07-01 2012-09-30
# 3       2012Q2       -4.39 2012-04-01 2012-06-30
# 4       2012Q1       -4.30 2012-01-01 2012-03-31
# 5       2011Q4       -4.40 2011-10-01 2011-12-31
# 6       2011Q3       -3.58 2011-07-01 2011-09-30
```

(you can set `frac` between 0 and 1 to indicate the fraction of the way through the period that you want; 0 means the beginning of the period and 1 means the end)

Comment: Just a side-question: is it also possible to get the last date of the quarterly period? For example `2012-12-31` for the first row here?